# Questions about polynomial systems with parameter

Tags: polynomials

We fix $n \geq 1$. Let $f$ be a continuous function $f : \mathbb R_+^*  \to \mathbb R^n$. Suppose that we have $n$ polynomials in $n+1$ variables

$$\begin{aligned} P_1(Y, X_1, \dots, X_n)\\ P_2(Y, X_1, \dots, X_n)\\ \vdots \qquad\\ P_n(Y,X_1,\dots,X_n)\end{aligned}$$

such that for $a \in \mathbb R_+^*, f(a)$ is an $\textbf{isolated}$ solution of the following system $(S_a)$ with unknown $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
         P_1(a,x_1,\dots,x_n) &= 0\\
         P_2(a,x_1,\dots,x_n) &= 0\\
                              &\vdots\\
         P_n(a,x_1,\dots,x_n) &= 0
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}

Finally we suppose that we have $p \geq 1$, such that for all $i$, $\mbox{deg} (P_i) \leq p$. I would like to:

- show that $f$ has a limit in $0$.
- show $f$ admits a Pusieux expansion near $0$.
- have information about the first term of this Puiseux series (depending on $n$ and $p$) to be able to give a majorant of the rate of convergence of $f$ to its limit in $0$.

I know that this question is really specific, and I don't know how hard it is since I don't know a lot about systems of polynomials equations.

Comment: This previous question discusses systems over complex numbers https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88867/puiseux-series-expansion-for-space-curves . For related algorithms, see Maurer, J. Manuscripta Math (1980) 32: 91. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01298184 and Jensen, A.N., Markwig, H. & Markwig, T. Collect. Math. (2008) 59: 129. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03191365

Comment: There's a book by Sturmfels, [_Solving systems of polynomial equations_](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf). It might be of some help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. In the answer by samuele in topic "Puiseux series expansion for space curves?", do you know if can we give a minoration of the integer $p$ he introduced ?

Comment: I meant  a majoration of the integer $p$ Samuele introduced, not a minoration sorry